# Divide and round

Tags: php, numbers

**$number = some number;**

When I divide this number, it gives not a round value.

Can give something like `3.13`.

**How to round it to the biggest value?**

Like:

```
if ($number == 3.5) {
    $number = 4;
} elseif ($number = 3.51) {
   $number = 4;
} else if ($number == 3.49) {
   $number = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the built in function `round()`. You can specify precision(how many decimal points you want) by using the function like so `round($float,$precision)`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: he/she is explicitly searching for ceil, not round

Comment: +1 to compensate for the -1 (Since your answer does exactly what the example provided intends)...  @Joe: But read the example.  If it's `3.49`, the expectation is `3`...  So `round()` does fit the code provided (granted, the text of the question is ambiguous at best, so I can see the point of contention)...

Comment: correct... didnt see that :P haha, well removing my vote and answer. "lord let it rain manpages"

Answer (score 1):

What about [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: he/she is explicitly searching for ceil, not round